# Objective-C : How to control volume of multiple audio players in DiracLE

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am creating a music app in **Objective C.** I need to play multiple sounds simultaneously and I am able to achieve this by using **DiracLE** audio players.

But the volume control method of this Library ***- (void) setVolume:(float)volume;*** doesn't seem to be working.

**My Code for initializing DiracAudioPlayer:**

```
DiracAudioPlayer *player1,*player2;
NSURL *url1,*url2;
NSError *error = nil;

url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song1" ofType:@"mp3"]];
url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song2" ofType:@"mp3"]];

player1 = [[DiracAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mainURL channels:1 error:&error];
[player1 setDelegate:self];
player2 = [[DiracAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mainURL channels:1 error:&error];
[player2 setDelegate:self];
```

**Method to set the player volumes:**

```
-(void)setPlayerVolume
{
   [player1 setVolume:0.5];
   [player2 setVolume:0.2];
}
```

**setVolume:** is not working even for single player and there are no exceptions being thrown.

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try my solution ? Did it work ?

Comment: @Elly_Philip Too bad :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also achieve this by initializing 2 `AVAudioPlayers` sequentially, and controlling the volume with `[self.player setVolume:volumeFloat];`

```
...   

    NSString *songA = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"songA" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSError *soundError = nil;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:songA] error:&soundError];
    if(self.player == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@",soundError);
    else
    {
        [self.player setDelegate:self];
        [self.player setVolume:0.75];
        [self.player play];
    }

    NSString *songB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"songB" ofType:@"mp3"];
    soundError = nil;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:songB] error:&soundError];
    if(self.player == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@",soundError);
    else
    {
        [self.player setDelegate:self];
        [self.player setVolume:0.25];
        [self.player play];
    }

...
```

In case you are determined to use DiracAudioPlayer, you could use your own method to reinitialize the AudioUnit with the right volume parameter in `DiracAudioPlayerBase.mm`:

```
-(void)setupInstanceWithUrl:(NSURL*)inUrl numChannels:(int)channels volume:(float)volume
{
    mDelegate = nil;
    mInUrl = [inUrl copy];
    mIsPrepared = NO;
    mIsProcessing = NO;
    mWorkerThread = nil;
    mTotalFramesInFile = 0;
    mIsRunning = NO;
    mVolume = volume;
    mLoopCount = mNumberOfLoops = 0;
    mHasFinishedPlaying = YES;

    if (channels < 1) channels = 1;
    else if (channels > 2) channels = 2;
    mNumChannels = channels;

    mPeak = new SInt16[mNumChannels];
    mPeakOut = new SInt16[mNumChannels];

    for (long v = 0; v < mNumChannels; v++) {
        mPeakOut[v] = 0;
        mPeak[v] = -1;
    }

    OSStatus status = noErr;
    mTimeFactor = 1./kOversample;
    mPitchFactor = kOversample;
    // This is boilerplate code to set up CoreAudio on iOS in order to play audio via its default output

    // Desired audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
#else
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput;
#endif
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    // Get ref to component
    AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // Get matching audio unit
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &mAudioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);

    // this is the format we want
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    mSampleRate=audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = mNumChannels;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = sizeof(short)*mNumChannels;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = sizeof(short)*mNumChannels;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(mAudioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &audioFormat,
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);

    // here we set up CoreAudio in order to call our PlaybackCallback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = PlaybackCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*) self;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(mAudioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &callbackStruct,
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));
    checkStatus(status);


    // Initialize unit
    status = AudioUnitInitialize(mAudioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);

    // here we allocate our audio cache
    mAudioBuffer = AllocateAudioBufferSInt16(mNumChannels, kAudioBufferNumFrames);

    // Avoid delay when hitting play by making sure the graph is pre-initialized
    AudioOutputUnitStart(mAudioUnit);
    AudioOutputUnitStop(mAudioUnit);

    [self prepareToPlay];

}
```

Double check that your volume is being set by logging:

```
NSLog(@"Volume P1: %f", [player1 volume]);
NSLog(@"Volume P2: %f", [player2 volume]);
```

In Addition you can also control the output volume of the mix, by the same method used by the hardware volume buttons: (This will launch the UI of a iOS volume change)

```
-(void)addVolumeObserver {

    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [MPVolumeView new];
    volumeView.showsRouteButton = NO;
    volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:volumeView];


    __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    [[volumeView subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
            strongSelf->volumeSlider = obj;
            [obj addTarget:strongSelf action:@selector(handleVolumeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
}

- (void)handleVolumeChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Volume: %f", volumeSlider.value);
}

- (void)setVolumeHandlerTo:(float)volume
{
    volumeSlider.value = volume;
}
```

Comment: I would like a reason for a downvote if possible. Maybe I can provide a better solution, or edit my answer to make it more understandable. Thanks